# I had to solve before being invited for the technical interview. could you guys take a look and advice me the proper answer?

Tags: testing, manual-testing

Function takes two and only two characters as input. It returns 1 when each entered symbol is either letter or number and 0 in other cases.
Numbers are Hindu-Arabic numerals from 0 to 9. Letters are Latin, Cyrillic or Modern Greek alphabet.

The bug was found before, slogan is: "Cyrillic letter can be treated as non-letter symbol"

Actions to reproduce:

Function input: ΑУ.

Expected output: 1. (Logic: only letters).

Observed output: 0.

The bug was fixed. Existing  tests  were  already  ran  as  a  regression test  after  bugfix, here   is   the  test report:

Input   Expected output Status
ΑΑ  1   Passed

1Α  1   Passed

11  1   Passed

Α$  0   Passed

(1  0   Passed

What tests cases will you do for bug's verification?
What tests cases will you propose to enforce regression testing of the function?
Negative tests like input less than 2 symbols and input more than 2 symbols are out of scope for both bug verification and additional regression test cases.
We will be glad to see your reasoning and argumentation as an addition, but the main thing is to provide test cases for both bug verification and additional regression test cases.

Comment: What pseuo-code have you tried? [ask]  -- your question sounds like we have to teach you about basic program logic.

Comment: I want test cases for both bug verification and additional regression test cases.